STM32F407VG Simulating positive quadrature stops working after setting frequency
First question on StackOverflow ever, so in case of any formatting error please let me know.
I'm working with a STM32F407VG microcontroller and basically managed to simulate a quadrature using TIM_OCMode_Toggle and setting CCR on the two different channels of the same timer. (Code Below)
void TIM3_Configuration_positive_quadrature(void)
{
    QuadratureFunctionAlreadyCalled = 1;

    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseStructure;
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef TIM_OCInitStructure;
    int Period;
    Period = 1000 / 1; //

    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode =     TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision =   TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period =          1000 - 1;
    //the prescaler is divided by 2 because the toggle mode (see below) halves the frequency.
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler =       ( TIM3_FREQ / LastSetFrequency ) / 2 - 1;

    TIM_TimeBaseInit( TIM3, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure );

    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_Toggle;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = (uint32_t)((Period * 1) / 4); // CH3 at 25%
    TIM_OC3Init(TIM3, &TIM_OCInitStructure);

    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = (uint32_t)((Period * 3) / 4); // CH4 at 75%, ie half cycle later
    TIM_OC4Init(TIM3, &TIM_OCInitStructure);


}

I have a function (SetFunction(uint16_t freq)) to set the frequency (Code body below)
        TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode =     TIM_CounterMode_Up;
        TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision =   TIM_CKD_DIV1;

        TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period =          TIM3_PERIOD - 1;
        TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler =       ( TIM3_FREQ / freq ) - 1;
        effective_freq = ( ( uint32_t )TIM3_FREQ / ( TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler + 1 ) );
        TIM_TimeBaseInit( TIM3, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure );

When I call the setFrequency(...) function and after TIM3_Configuration_positive_quadrature(...) I manage to see a positive quadrature via Oscilloscope.
The problem arises when I call the setFrequency(...) function once again, the quadrature either keeps being positive or goes negative, next to it I can call TIM3_Configuration_positive_quadrature(...) how many times I want but nothing happens.
Don't know how to create a quadrature simulation function that works everytime I call it.
Tried with creating a function that simply sets CCR3 and CCR4 of TIM3 but with no avail, once the frequency function gets called the functions don't work anymore.

What's this, SPL? But why?
I don't know what TIM_TimeBaseInit() in SPL does, but if it resets the timer's counter, then depending on the moment when it's called, it may generate an edge on the output where edge was just generated before, resulting in two consecutive edges on the same output. And that means direction reversal.
There may be other scenarios how this could go wrong, especially if you want to change frequency on the go.
Getting this working as expected in all possible cases may get tricky, especially if you want to depend on some "library" - you may be better off with the control provided by register level programming.
Or, maybe even better, if you don't need to generate too high frequencies, do it in software: just maintain a circular counter and output to two GPIOs accordingly in an interrupt.

Hi! Thanks for taking time to answer. TIM_TimeBaseInit() does not reset the CNT register.

As I suspected, it does. I dug out a collection of SPLs for 'F4, and indeed, last line in TIM_TimeBaseInit() is TIMx->EGR = TIM_PSCReloadMode_Immediate;   which sets TIMx_EGR.UG, thus generates Update event, which in the default Upcounting mode clears TIMx_CNT, read description of TIMx_EGR.UG in the RM.

Thank you so much! By removing that line it actually works.
